# I can't receive the full image using a server Flask and Okhttp

Tags: flask, okhttp

I'm trying to make an app which sends a image to a server, it transforms the image and it return to the app. But when the app receive the image, only receive a part of it. I did a web with flask and I saw that it send well the picture, and I used Okhttp to download a picture from Internet I don't have any problem.

To send the picture from server I've used:
`return flask.send_from_directory('path')` and `return flask.send_file(...)`

To send and receive the picture in the client I've used:

```
void postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();
                Log.d("FAIL", e.getMessage());

                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        responseText.setText(R.string.ip_failure);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView responseText = findViewById(R.id.responseText);
                        responseText.setText("");
                        try {
                            Bitmap imagenGAN;
                            imagenGAN = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
                            ImageView imagen = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                            imagen.setImageBitmap(imagenGAN);
                            SaveImage(imagenGAN);
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Example of the received image:

[image]

I don't know why I don't receive the full image. Can someone help me?